# Is it better to use activation (ReLu) layer after Global Average pooling layer?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have seen most have used non-linearity -> GAP -> Dense. But in some have used following order; GAP -> non-linearity -> Dense. Which is better? Is it good to use activation layer after GAP? (Here, GAP means Global Average Pooling layer)

Comment: Normally, it's not a problem to use non-linearity function before or after pooling layer. (E.g. Maxpooling layer). But in the case of Average Polling it's better to use non-linearity function before Average pooling. (E.g. Global average pooling)